# Text to image conversion for table not working when running back end php to get the table data

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

So I have a drop down selector when certain items are ticked, it filters based on SQL WHERE parameter. 
I'm doing this the way [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34144993/8311216) describes it

For most part, it works completely fine, and if I open the back end file directly the conversion of value to image works fine.

[This is what it looks like when I open the back end directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpvTr.png)

However, from my main page, if I try to call this back end php it does not show the image at all.

[Instead shows up like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRliK.png)

To convert the image we are using this javascript

```
$.expr[':'].textEquals = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().match("^" + arg + "$");
        };
    }
);
```

along with something like this

```
$('.spec:textEquals("1")').html("<img id='id' title='title' src='src'/>");
```

Any help to resolve this problem would be appreciated

Comment: Why can't you get the image path to front end ?

Comment: @Sameera Im using the javascript in the front end to convert the id to corresponding images